# What movie is Kevin from?

Tags: reference, props, the-cabin-in-the-woods

In Cabin in the Woods, there is a board with a list of monsters on it:

[image: image showing whiteboard listing various horror movie monsters]

Between Deadites and Mummy in the lower left, there is Kevin. I am Kevin. I would like to know what monster reference this is to, as most of these are references to other movies.

Comment: As a "Jason," I can understand your interest in this.

Comment: Kevin in my opinion is the Killer robot. mainly because I dont see killer robot on the list and I know thier was one in the movie.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [Official Visual Companion](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/9141341) to *The Cabin in the Woods*:

> *Some stuff had to get cut from the monster rampage sequence at the end. The Angry Molesting Tree, which you can glimpse in the elevator in one scene, got much more molest-y in another shot, which might wind up as a DVD extra. **Also, one of Goddard's favorite monsters was Kevin, a sweet-looking guy who seemed like he might work at Best Buy — until he dismembers people.***

Comment: I look forward to the uncut version of the movie and i felt it would've been awesome if they had added "Sweet dreams are made of this"

Comment: I was just about to post this. I hope the Visual Companion has a picture of Kevin.

Answer (score 5):

Have you  watched [Sin city](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin_City_%28film%29)? I am supposing that Elija Wood's character Kevin could be the reference. I thought it could be a take on Jason from the story writer's perspective.

Comment: That is a good one! Makes sense to. Can you find any confirmation from the writers?

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbeled across this movie title the other day, and it reminded me of this question.  The movie title was [We Need To Talk About Kevin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Need_to_Talk_About_Kevin_%28film%29).  I believe that this may have been the movie that was being referenced on the white board.  here's part of the plot synopsis from Wikipedia:

> Adolescent Kevin Katchadourian (Ezra Miller) is in prison after
>   committing a massacre at his high school. His mother, Eva (Swinton), a
>   once-successful travel writer, lives alone in a run-down house and
>   works in a mall travel agency in a town near the prison where she
>   visits Kevin. She looks back at her memories of him growing up as she
>   tries to cope with the anger and hostility of her neighbours, who know
>   her to be Kevin's mother. Her memories are shown in flashbacks.

Comment: I didn't know about this movie when I asked this question. I think he might be the inspiration for Kevin but there isn't anything confirming that. Although it's not unusual for Joss Whedon to include an undefined monster with a normal name.

Comment: For anyone checking the math, the movie came out in 2011 and the novel came out in 2003. *Cabin in the Woods* was *released* in 2012, so it may have been inspired by the novel rather than the film adaptation.

Answer (score 0):

"Kevin" is an analogue to "Jason" from the **Friday the 13th** movies. (It may also be a reference to [Kevin Williamson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0932078/), the writer of the **Scream** films.)